# I'm running a private Ethereum network, how to properly share my enode address with my friends?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, privacy, enode, tor

I have setup a private network and I'm looking for advice on a few things.

According to the [official guide](https://ethereum.org/de/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/) I can use Tor onion addresses.

My question is how do I share this address properly? I have yet to get someone try to connect/sync to my node so I want to solve this issue preventively.

Currently I have this:

```
enode://bde14f3e10cd6626dd1aae7c95ec28b644ceb93be31869717a0a85c86c510d319fd267d6ef30dd75fabfab49f310c53c643a4df722647fc27fdb667d14b64d5a@jcjs77umt7k2c4z2.onion:8085
```

I found old posts that say that Ethereum doesn't work with Tor, but I think they were referring to UDP discovering? As I won't be needing discovering for this project I think Tor is fine for now, since not every member of my discord server can afford a private IP.

Is my format correct, would this work? Or do I have to share my Tor IP instead of the tor hostname?